# How to trigger a browserstack build from Gitlab pipeline, and get result- pass/fail

Tags: gitlab, appium, browserstack

We have an Android project, and are using Appium together with Browserstack to do UI testing. Uploading the APK to Browserstack via Gitlab is straightforward. But triggering the appium test, and getting the result (pass/fail) on the Gitlab pipeline, does not seem to be documented. What is the recommended approach to perform this task?